# Grouping and counting in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <FT>Paket</FT>
   <FT>Parti</FT>
   <FT>Paket</FT>
   <FT>Styche</FT>
   <FT>Styche</FT>
</root>
```

And I want my output to display such as -

```
Paket   2
Parti   1
Styche  2
```

Its is grouping the value of elements and the no. is showing the total count of the value being repeated.
Like Paket is indicating the value and it is being repeated 2 times in the XML.

How the logic will work?

Comment: I cannot write the code here as it is an image output. I tried with group and count functions, but not receiving the result which I want.

Answer (score 2):

**In XSLT 1.0, using Muenchian grouping:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="k" match="FT" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="FT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', .))]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FT">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', count(key('k', .)))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
Paket 2
Parti 1
Styche 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to apply the above logic without templates. If that can be done. Though I applied <xsl:apply-templates select="FT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', .))]"/>, it genearted the Paket, Parti... but when I added <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>, it didn't went to the next line. Also, <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', count(key('k', .)))"/> didn't worked. Because I didn't applied template to it.