# Counting frequency of tags / attributes in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

As an extension to the question that solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522245/get-tag-name-attribute-name-in-xml-using-xslt), how we can count number of frequency of each tag and attribute?

For example, for this document:

```
<a>
<apple color="red"/>
<banana color="yellow"/>
<sugar taste="sweet"/>
<cat size="small"/>
</a>
```

something like this result (preferably in two separate tables) is desired:

For tags: apple = 1, banana =1, sugar =1, cat=1

For attributes: color= 2, taste=1, size=1

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search, it's one of the most often asked questions here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I have researched a lot (here and in other forums), but the provided solutions were not applicable for this case (at least, I could not find the appropriate ones!). Anyway, I'm continue researching.

Comment: @EiliaAbraham, see this ANSWER, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19828481/3049413

Comment: @Rudramuni TP, Thanks for that, it seems it answered my problem in reverse direction. So, it can be regarded as a good starting point to working on. Moreover, I'm currently considering [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/countelementwithcertainattributename.htm)

Comment: Also, it is very helpful: (http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="kEleName" match="*" use="local-name()"/>
<xsl:key name="kAttribName" match="@*" use="local-name()"/>

<xsl:variable name="var1">
    <xsl:for-each select="/a/*/@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kAttribName', name()))]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(.), ' ', count(key('kAttribName', name(.))))"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
        <xsl:text>,&#160;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kEleName', name()))]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1"><xsl:text>For tags:&#160;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(.), ' ', count(key('kEleName', name(.))))"/>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
                <xsl:text>,&#160;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;For attributes:&#160;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
            </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<a>
    <apple color="red"/>
    <apple color="green"/>
    <banana color="yellow"/>
    <sugar taste="sweet"/>
    <cat size="small"/>
</a>
```

OutPut:

```
For tags: apple 2, banana 1, sugar 1, cat 1 
For attributes: color 3, taste 1, size 1
```